# Problem with creating variable in loop

Tags: python, loops

I'm learning python with a book that teaches by creating games. I have to write the code so I input a number and the computer makes educated guesses based on higher or lower input. I keep getting an error after inputting my number:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Rayvenx\Desktop\My_programs\Number_game_pcguess.py", line 7, in 
    highlow = raw_input("\nIs it", guess, "?:")
TypeError: [raw_]input expected at most 1 arguments, got 3
```

Here's the code:

```
import random

number = raw_input("\nWhat is your number 1-100? :")

guess = random.randrange(100) + 1

highlow = raw_input("\nIs it", guess, "?:")

while guess != number:
    if highlow == "lower":
        guess = random.randrange(100) + 1  guess

        highlow = raw_input("\nIs it", guess, "?:")


print "\nHaha! I win!"

raw_input("\n\nPress enter to exit game.")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are giving `raw_input` three arguments when it expects one ;)

But, seriously: your calls which look like `raw_input("is it", guess, "?:")` should use Python's string formatting to format the string being passed to `raw_input`: `raw_input("is it %s?" %(guess, ))`.

Comment: I don't know what that means x_x I've written about a dozen programs. All have went well up until this one. I can't figure out how to make the computer "guess" less than or more than the previous given number.

Comment: That seems like a different problem than the one you've posted about here. If my solution (or another solution) works for you, you should upvote + accept it (or them), then ask a new question for this other question you have.

Comment: I got the same error when substituting raw_input("is it %s?" %(guess, ))

Comment: Have you change all the calls to `raw_input`?

Comment: Like I said, I'm new to this. Not sure what you mean. I pasted what you wrote into the code in place of how I had it written <raw_input("is it %s?" %(guess, ))> and it gave me the same error.

Comment: I think it's referring to this line when it says line 7: guess = random.randrange(100) + 1 < guess. Is it possible to write it so the number can be equal to something manipulated by itself like that?

Comment: If you look at the error, it will tell you what line caused the error. Check that line in your code to make sure that you are only supplying one argument to `raw_input` (eg, you are using `raw_input("...." %(...))` and not `raw_input("...", ..., "...")`.

Comment: If you're getting a different error (ie, unrelate to `raw_input`), then you should accept an answer to this question and post a new question about the new problem.

Comment: (however, yes: it is possible to change the value of a variable based on that variable. For example, `x = x * 3` is just fine)

Comment: No problem :) If you comment here with new questions (so I'll be notified), I could help you with them, too.

Answer (score 1):

```
highlow = raw_input("\nIs it %s?:"%guess)
```

Or, using the format method (introduced in Python 2.6):

```
highlow = raw_input("\nIs it {0}?:".format(guess))
```

Or, using if Python3:

```
highlow = raw_input("\nIs it {}?:".format(guess))
```

Answer (score 1):

This line is passing 3 arguments.

```
highlow = raw_input("\nIs it", guess, "?:")
```

Format the string outside or format the string inside

```
mystr = "\nIs it %s ?;" % guess
highlow = raw_input(mystr)
```

or

```
highlow = raw_input("\nIs it %s ?;" % guess)
```